waitForSelector not recognizing my different components to be present in the DOM
I'm writing a test in signin.test.js and my project is a React.js app, but it's failing to recognize different elements using waitForSelector. Despite setting up the selectors correctly, the test is not waiting for the expected elements to be visible/rendered.
I'm using Jest with Puppeteer for browser automation. I've checked the selectors using the browser's dev tools and they seem correct. I've also tried increasing the timeout for waitForSelector, but it still fails.
Here's a simplified version of my signin.test.js file:
// page imports

import GeneralNavbarPage from '../../pages/components/general/GeneralNavbarPage';
import SignInPage from '../../pages/components/user/SignInPage';

// local imports
const mongoDBUtils = require('../../../../mongodb/mongodb.utils');

describe('Sign In', () => {
    let signInPage
    let generalNavbarPage

    beforeAll(async () => {
        try {
            // instantiate database
            await mongoDBUtils.connect();
            await mongoDBUtils.instantiateDatabase();
            await mongoDBUtils.disconnect();

        
            signInPage = new SignInPage()
            generalNavbarPage = new GeneralNavbarPage()
            await signInPage.visit()
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }

    })

    afterAll(async () => {
        // drop database
        try {
            await mongoDBUtils.connect();
            await mongoDBUtils.dropDatabase();
            await mongoDBUtils.disconnect();
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
    })

    it("should have a sign in heading", async () => {
        jest.setTimeout(10000); 
        await signInPage.isSignInHeadingDisplayed()
        
    })

    it("should have a sign in text in heading", async () => {
        jest.setTimeout(10000); 
        await signInPage.checkSignInFormHeading()
    })
 
    //other tests//
})

Below is a segment of my SignInPage.js
// package imports
const percySnapshot = require('@percy/puppeteer')

// local imports
import BasePage from '../../BasePage';

export default class SignInPage extends BasePage {

    async visit() {
        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/user/signin')
    }

    async isSignInLinkDisplayed() {
        await page.waitForSelector('#signin-btn')
    }


    async isSignInHeadingDisplayed() {
        await page.waitForSelector("#login-heading")
    }


    //other tests// 
}

I have checked my react component and both #signin-btn and #login-heading are there. Also when I run the test, the page is rendered and even fills out both text input fields before closing
http://localhost:3000/user/signin
<div>
  <ErrorBoundary errorAt="At User SignIn GeneralNavbar">
    <GeneralNavbar history={props.history} isSignInPage={true} />
  </ErrorBoundary>
  <div className="p-3 col-md-4 mt-5 mb-5 offset-md-4" style={theme.form}>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ paddingLeft: "10%", paddingRight: "10%" }}>
      <h2 id="login-heading" style={theme.heading}>Sign In to your account</h2>
      <br />

      {/* other components */}

      <button
        className="btn mt-2"
        id="signin-btn"
        type="submit"
        style={theme.formSubmit}
        disabled={isLoading2}
      >
        {isLoading2
          ? <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
          : null
        }
        Sign In
      </button>

      {/* other components */}

  </div>
</div>

How can I troubleshoot and fix the issue with waitForSelector not recognizing different elements in my signin.test.js file?
Adding a minimal reproducible example of my package.json
{
  "name": "minimal-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Minimal reproducible example with Jest setup",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest --verbose --detectOpenHandles --force-exit",
    "test:integration": "jest ./test_framework/integration/client --verbose --detectOpenHandles --force-exit",
    "test:e2e": "jest ./test_framework/E2E/tests/user/signin.test.js --verbose --force-exit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-html-reporter": "^3.3.0",
    "jest-puppeteer": "^5.0.2",
    "puppeteer": "^9.0.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  }
}


Your selectors look just fine based on your markup, so the problem must be something you're not showing here. Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] with package.json. Thanks. There's no need for timeouts when you use waitForSelector.

Just added an image of the package.json

Please make it text, not an image. The code isn't a minimal example yet--it's not runnable or complete.
